# Phonegap plugin creation for cross platform

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins

Whether I can create a phonegap plugin java ? any example

If I create java in plugin, whether I can use it for all the platforms ?

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/tree/DEPRECATED) you have tons of plugins to take a look

If you create a java plugin it might work on android and blackberry. For iOS you need objective-c. But you can use the same javascript for all of them.